# Kendo Window pop-up appears twice when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some issues with Kendo Window after clicking a button that has a JS function

CSS Class

```
.addUserWindow  {

    padding-top: 29px;
    min-width: 90px;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 440px;
    display: block;
    top: 383px;
    left: 740px;
    z-index: 10005;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

My Kendo Window

```
 @(Html.Kendo()
              .Window()
              .Name("myWindow")
              .Title("Add")
              .Visible(false)
              .Modal(true)
              .Draggable(true)
              .Width(440)
              .Height(600).HtmlAttributes(new {@class= "addUserWindow adminOnlyClass" })
        )
```

And my JS function

```
function openWindow() {
    var wdw = $("#myWindow").data("kendoWindow");
                    wdw.open();  
    }
```

And my command

```
    columns.Command(commands =>
                                                                                     {
commands.Custom(" ").Click("openWindow").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "addUser" }).HtmlAttributes(new { Title = "Adauga User la Grup " });
                                                                                     }).Title("").Width(50);
```

Indeed the second one is empty, it doesn't have any header. Does someone knows how to get rid of the 2nd pop-up?

Comment: Is it possible your parent (if you have one) view or anything other that is attached to the page (or even the page itself) has got #myWindow defined apart from your window already?

Comment: @Adriani6 No. I noticed that if I delete the class from the Window declaration, the 2nd one disappears, but I have to put the addUserWindow class to my kendo window

Comment: Strange. Which version of Kendo are you running? The 2017 is a little buggy I personally encountered dataviz issues and had to revert back to older version of 2016.

Comment: Do you still get the 2nd popup if you remove the wdw.open()? I believe just setting that window reference may automatically run the open method.

Comment: @Adriani6 Unfortunately, the 2017 version

Comment: @Sage If I remove it, my window won't open

Comment: @GeorgeGreat of course it won't. Try using kendo 2016 scripts and see if you can issue still occurs, you might want to check if there's a more up to date version too, otherwise your best bet would be to submit a ticket to Telerik with your issue and see if its a bug.